# PHP JavaBridge Not Finding Java Classes Ubuntu 12.0.4 Precise PHP 5.3 Tomcat7

Tags: java, php, class, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I downloaded the JavaBridge.war file and deflated it within a folder inside my Apache www folder named "JavaBridge." So the path will be:

```
http://myhost.com/JavaBridge/
```

All the "hello.php" and "test.php" or "excel.php" are contained in the root of that folder. i. e.:
    http://myhost.com/JavaBridge/index.php

PHP is working because if I go to that path the `phpinfo()` function shows my PHP config. The problem is that the Java Classes are not being picked up.

Both Apache, Tomcat7 and Java are running. I have the default jdk installed.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I visit the hello.php file within that directory, the Apache logs show the following:

```
[error] [client myhost] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: language in /var/www/JavaBridge/hello.php on line 11
```

This is the content of this file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hello</title>
<body>
<TABLE border='1'>
<tr>
<th>English</th>
<th><?php
 $lang=$_GET['language'];
 if(!isset($lang)) $lang="cs_CZ";
 echo $lang?>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello</td>
<td>
<?php
if(!function_exists("bindtextdomain")) die("function bindtextdomain not found. Please       install language support, see http://php.net for details");
bindtextdomain("hello", "./locale");
textdomain("hello");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
echo _("hello");
?>
</td>
</tr>
</TABLE>
<form>
<p>
<select name='language'>
<option value="cs_CZ">cs_CZ (Czech)</option>
<option value="de_DE">de_DE (German)</option>
<option value="he_IL">he_IL (Hebrew)</option>
<option value="ja_JP">ja_JP (Japanese)</option>
</select>
<p>
<input type="submit" default="cs_CZ" value="Update"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already placed 3 library files from `WEB-INF` after deflating JavaBridge.war within `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` as recommended in some tutorials.

I have already added a webapp config within `/etc/tomcat7/web.xml` as suggested in other tutorials.

Can someone explain why is it so difficult to make JavaBridge work and what to do?

Comment: Can you also include the error you are seeing from the Apache Logs.

Comment: Is there: [error] [client myhost] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: language in /var/www/JavaBridge/hello.php on line 11

Comment: Did you really request `.../hello.php?language=blah`? If not, why do you think `$_GET['language']` would be defined?

Comment: No. I requested http://myhost.com/JavaBridge/hello.php. In that page there is a dropdown with predefined languages to choose from. I should not need to request the language in my query string. It should work. It would be defined if PHP would find the Java class path that defines it, and it is not.

Comment: <?php
 $lang=$_GET['language'];
 if(!isset($lang)) $lang="cs_CZ";
 echo $lang?>

Comment: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/installation.php It does not say I have to do anything else.

Comment: `$lang=$_GET['language'];` <-- see that line? That's throwing your notice if you don't have `language=SOMETHING` in your query string.

Answer (score 0):

As Carsten said, "`$lang=$_GET['language'];` is throwing your notice if you don't have language=SOMETHING in your query string".

P.S. Try not to leave the questions unanswered.